# how to disable zoom on y-axis only in a dygraph

Tags: dygraphs

Is it possible to disable zooming on just the vertical axis in a dygraph?  I don't see any explicit means of doing this.

Thanks,

Andy

Answer (score 4):

There's no built-in option for this. You can approximate it with a zoomCallback that resets the vertical range, i.e.

```js
g = new Dygraph(div, data, {
  valueRange: [0, 10],
  zoomCallback: function() {
    g.updateOptions({zoomRange: [0, 10]});
  }
});
```

You can see an example of this [here](http://jsfiddle.net/eM2Mg/2640/). You might also want to star [this](https://github.com/danvk/dygraphs/issues/374) related feature request.

Answer (score 1):

There is a function which does the vertical zooming. Override the function in your application.

`Dygraph.prototype.doZoomY_ = function(lowY, highY) {
    return;
};`

Comment: While I think this works, it's generally not encouraged to mess with any variable with a _ in the name in Dygraphs, so just be aware that funky stuff may happen.

Answer (score 0):

Set a zoomCallback function that resets the zoom, like this:

```
g = new Dygraph(div, data, {
  zoomCallback: function() {
    this.resetZoom();
  }
});
```